# Will programmable keyboards send keystrokes successfully to Windows 10 logon screen?

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, keyboard

Can a [programmable keyboard like this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B014EZ43I6) successfully send keystrokes to a Windows 10 logon screen? For example, say my windows password was "monkey", could I program a key on the programmable keyboard that, when pressed, would send the keystrokes for "monkey" followed by ENTER, and would I be logged in?

Comment: If it supports `Enter` key, I can't see a problem doing this, all you have to do before doing this, is set focus to password field and run macros.

Answer (score 1):

Although a security risk I believe it is actually possible to create macros for a password.  At https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-ww/support/how-to/keyboard/macros you can find the information you need to create one.

Comment: Please, don't think Im trying to fight with you, but link you posted is regarding a macros that one can create on a "Windows" side. The keyboard OP mentioned is able to remember key-presses on its side, in its own memory , on its own microcontroller (inside keyboard if you want). It is completely dedicated external solutions that isn't related to Windows, Mac or FreeBSD. It is an external device with extra capabilities, independent from any operation systems. I hope I clarified what i meant.

Comment: I realize that. I feel the answer is still relevant. I am unsure if the keyboard with its features can specifically create a macro for a password, if it can great if it can't well there is still hope in the link. Also your more than welcome to edit my answer. We are both for the achievement of the same goal here.

Comment: (Y) , If one want to use some macros while logged-in in a windows, your solution would work, but as you correctly said previously, - not for a password related workflows.